# Enable dynatrace chrome extension protractor config

Tags: google-chrome, protractor, dynatrace

I want to enable dynatrace on the browser instances that are to run on the selenium grid.
How can i enable the dynatrace extension on chrome via a protractor config file?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you talk about the Dynatrace UEM Injection plugin. Instead of doing this through the Chrome plugin i suggest you enable Dynatrace UEM for the whole application by installing a dynatrace agent on your application. The other approach would be to install a proxy server, e.g: Apache andinstall dynatrace there and then simply configure that proxy in your Chrome. From now on you automatically get Dynatrace UEM support
I recently showed how this work in my dynatrace youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OSSKwD4WKQ&index=50&list=PLqt2rd0eew1bmDn54E2_M2uvbhm_WxY_6

Andi